# Windows generate Google cloud Endpoints client libraries Step by Step

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Hi guys I have a problem with generate Google cloud enpoints libraries for my android client on Android Studio with my windows machine. I tried to follow these steps illustrated at this link:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool#generating_a_client_library_bundle_from_a_backend_api

But I have no idea right path in which I have to run the following command

```
appengine-java-sdk-x.x.x/bin/endpoints.sh get-client-lib --war=target/helloendpoints-1.0-SNAPSHOT \
-bs gradle com.google.appengine.samples.helloendpoints.Greetings
```

Could someone tell me what I should do step by step?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Endpoints entirely from within Android Studio without going to a command prompt/terminal. Here is a link with references to further information: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/clients/android/